# Getting child gmail account to work on Chromium

Tags: raspberry-pi, gmail, chromium, raspbian

I bought a Raspberry Pi 3 to teach my kid to code; it also makes their web-browsing visible to me as she can only use it through the TV. However, I've run into an irritating problem: her gmail account won't load on Chromium. There's not even an error beyond saying

> Oops, there's been a problem. Try again later.

The thing is, my own gmail accounts load just fine. I can only assume that this is because her account is for under 12's? If so, is there any way I can enable it, as I'd prefer to have her use email in the open where I can monitor it? Thanks.

Comment: Have you setup Google API keys for Chromium?

Comment: No, I haven't. I wasn't aware that I needed to? Especially given that some gmail accounts work but not others. I'll look into doing it and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to fix the issue by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

In Chromium Setting, under Advanced, In Privacy and Security - turn off Allow chromium sign-in.  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't answer his question. This issue is most likely because of Chromium's missing Google API keys